If Jesus is the Creator in Col 1:16, then why does Col 1:18 say that he "becomes preeminent" if he, as the Creator and God, is already preeminent?

He is the head of the body, the assembly, who is the beginning, the firstborn from the dead, that in all things he might have the preeminence.
— Colossians 1:18 — World English Bible


Interesting. All 4 answers each have 2 down-votes.

In context, Paul's assertion of preeminence applies narrowly in this case to Jesus in relation to the resurrected believers. @Ray, apparently upvotes and downvotes now correlate with agreement or disagreement in opinion regardless of hermeneutical value.

Maybe the moderators can account for the down votes for users that are down voting without specifying their reasons for their votes. Others always make it obvious when they upvote by noting that in their comments, I wonder if they do the same when they downvote.

The issue revolves around the use of a ἵνα clause with the subjunctive.
The answer to a different question provides a good background.
Does Ἵνα (hina) clause convey certainty or uncertainty?
 In fact, it basically answers the question.  The OP's question, in that question, says,

"the hina clause does not imply uncertainty when paired with the
subjunctive but implies that in order for the end to happen, the first
condition must be fulfilled. "

That's a very important point.  Read the full question and answers for the full context.
But, specific to Colossians 1:18, after a list (in some sense, even a list of lists) describing the authority and position of Jesus, Paul says:
ἵνα     γένηται    ἐν    πᾶσιν      αὐτὸς πρωτεύων,
so that may become among all things he    preeminent.

So, this is a ἴνα plus the subjunctive clause; what does that mean?  Taking from the question referenced above,

The conjunction ἵνα (hina) is a conjunction which means (BDAG)

marker to denote purpose, aim, or goal, in order that, that,


So, the ἴνα clause is answering the question, "What is the purpose of all these attributes just listed?"  Wording that in English can trip up interpreters of the English. "What does the may, or might, or whatever, mean?" The Greek is standard stuff.  The answer:  It's a purpose or goal clause.
A couple of interesting pieces that help further substantiate Paul's point of Christ's preeminence could be mentioned.
The αὐτὸς ('he') is nominative, so it's the subject of the verb γένηται ('may become').  Technically, 'he' is not needed, the verb already supplies the subject; however, its use and position in the clause (interestingly) emphasize it.  It's sort of preeminent.
Secondly, πρωτεύων ('preeminence') is a present participle.  So, it serves as a predicate adjective but with a verbal (ie. action) component. It's also nominative, the naming case (which is not unusual for the verb γίνομαι).  It conveys the sense of "being preeminent".  The purpose of all those attributes that Paul listed was that Christ may become one who is identified as being preeminent.  I think the fact that this is a present active nominative participle removes any contingency meaning provided by the subjunctive main verb.
Basically, it says:  Christ is preeminent; here are the attributes that make that true.
One last thing.  This letter is more accurately to be thought of as a sermon. Because it would have been delivered as a verbally articulated message--it was read aloud by the person Paul sent with it to deliver it.  It's an oral culture.  This fact becomes interesting when you read a section that gives a list and then ends with the most prominent of words, which is exactly what happens here.  Think about how that probably sounded in a sermon.  When I read this, I hear:
A list of items followed by
"so that he may become among everything
<pause>
<increasing volume>
Himself
<pause>
<increasing volume>
preeminent!"
And if you think that's subjective on my part, then please consider that the word order and word choice, as well as being an oral culture, support this understanding.  We tend to think of word order as being relatively only about semantics.  In an oral culture, it's also about the oral delivery and the aural reception of the words.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This illustrates one of the problems with relying on only the KJV, whose language is over 400 years old.
The problem spreads to other translations that copy its style.
Over time, usage and meaning can change.
(Think of Fred Flintstone having "a gay old time", and what that means today. Or know that until even more recently, applying the term "gender" to a human was considered a joking insult.)
The word "might" here is the past tense of "may", which means to be permitted. "might" is used today even less than "may" (e.g. most people now say "can", which means ability, not permission).
The NewKJV avoids the problem by putting it in the present tense.
This is actually quite appropriate, since the Greek word for preeminance, "πρωτεύων", is a present active participle, indicating that it is Jesus's present state:

And He is the head of the body, the church, who is the beginning, the firstborn from the dead, that in all things He may have the preeminence.

It's saying that because Jesus is the firstborn, he is allowed to have the preeminence (over his yet to be born younger siblings).

+1.  I think this is an excellent answer that addresses this rather adroitly.  many thanks for a good answer.  This could be further improved by observing that πρωτεύων is present active thus making it current and not a future state.  That is, Jesus, "is holding preeminence"

@JoshuaB, the scripture says "the firstborn from the dead". It has nothing to do with whether Christ had a beginning, or what his part was in the Creation; it has everything to do with being given eternal life after dying as a mortal human.

Dottard & RayButterworth - Of course Jesus is "holding preeminence", because God begot (created) Christ as the first of all creatures, creating him on Day 1 as the Light of the world. Then, God created the rest of all things through Jesus by giving him the orders to carry out the works from Day 2 to Day 6. And Ray, Jesus is "firstborn from the dead" so that He can be first in all things, both in mortality and in immortality.

Giving him the orders as in, marching orders?  God was too busy with other matters, or too worn out, to do any more creating?

My Parable of the Arbor Gate
Many years ago, I designed and built an arbor gate. First, I envisioned it in my mind. Then, using my hands, I drew up the plan, cut the pieces, and put it together.
It was the work of Dieter’s hands that revealed the design in his mind. Unfortunately, some of my kids could argue for the trinity of Dieter, namely Dieter the father, Dieter’s imagination, and Dieter’s hands.

Other kids could argue that they have only ONE father, whose mind devises stupid dad jokes, and who occasionally builds things, not THREE fathers! The “Dieter-trinitarians” argue that Dieter, his mind, and his hands are coequal, while others argue that if Dieter created the arbor gate, he musta created his mind and his hands as well.
Still others (we have a lot of kids) argue that Dieter’s hands were really only an extension of his mind and the arbor gate was entirely metaphorical, while still others say that a pair of hands achieved Dieterity by obedience to Dieter’s mind.
However, Dieter contends that while his hands and mind are all part of Dieter, they do have a separateness but still all are a part of Dieter and do the will of Dieter. Then there's the debate over whether Dieter's hands have one nature or two natures (is handedness ascribed to Dieter's mind and what about his dirty fingernails).
One of Dieter's neighbors thinks the arbor gate musta evolved naturally and spontaneously, obviously shaped by differential erosion. Dieter’s wife wishes the kids would finally stop arguing and take out the garbage.
Explanation and Motive
Please do not think that my parable attempts to explain God. It emphatically does not!
Instead, I'm demonstrating the utter futility of trying to extend the scriptural description of God as our Father  and Jesus his Son any further than what the scriptures reveal. The attempts to do so have been futile, divisive, and most certainly wrong.
Thus, I'm mocking the theological attempts at explaining God with how ridiculous it sounds when applied to a human.

Interesting that the range of answers here goes from the sublime to the ridiculous, yet both types play an important part in answering the Q. Be it preeminent position in Greek grammar, or the parable of the arbor gate, lessons can be learned and applied. The question is, who's up for thoughtfully combining both in order to get the point? +1

Actually, there's an implied kal v'chomer argument here: if you get muddled by trying to define Dieter, how much more muddled will you get by trying to understand an infinitely more amazing God. This is why I refuse to deviate from the descriptions revealed in the scriptures. God already gave us analogies, personifications, and qualities that we can use, and cautioned us against pretending to understand his thoughts and his ways.

The problem with this analogy is that no one could plausibly be so confused about Dieter unless they were first confused about God and then tried to export their confusion to a story about Dieter and the Arbor gate.

@Austin, the first use of this analogy is in Deuteronomy 32:6, "Do you thus repay the Lord, you foolish and senseless people? Is not he your father, who created you, who made you and established you?" (ESV) This is from the words of the song that God gave to Moses. People don't learn fatherhood by understanding God, they learn fatherhood by becoming fathers.

Answer
The answer is rather very simple:
Jesus, though “in the form of God” with preeminence of God “emptied Himself” of the same preeminence and took “the form of a slave” (Phlp 2:6-7).
Explanation
So, God the Father restored the preeminence back to Him just as He prayed to Him:

“And now Father, glorify Me with Yourself, with the glory which I
had with You before the existence of the world” (John 17:5).

(Jesus had the same glory that the Father has; a creature cannot have the same glory of God).
Apostle Paul says the same thing:

“Because of this also God highly exalted Him and gave Him a name above
every name” (Phlp 2:9).

Paul then clearly identifies this exalted name of Jesus that is above every name: YAHWEH or JEHOVAH!!! (Phlp 2:10-11).
Yes, Paul confirms this by quoting Isaiah 45:23.
Isaiah 45:23

“I (Yahweh) have sworn by Myself, the Word has gone out of My mouth in
righteousness, and shall not return, that to Me every knee SHALL
bow, every tongue SHALL swear”.

The highlighted part is given in the future tense. This shows that this is a prophecy for the future times when the entire humanity will recognize the true God. The children of Israel were already bowing and confessing Yahweh as their only God.
Yet, Yahweh says every tongue and knee “shall”: this includes the entire humanity besides the children of Israel.
As usual, several of the Bible prophecies have partial fulfillment in the present times. So, presently we see that the Gentile people all over the world already kneeling before Lord Jesus Christ and confessing Him as the Lord!
This proves that Isaiah 45:23 is getting fulfilled in Jesus Christ.
This is exactly what the Apostle Paul says, by citing Isaiah 45:23, in Philippians 2:10-11:

“that at the name of Jesus "every knee should bow," of heavenly
ones, and earthly ones, and ones under the earth, and "every tongue
should confess" that Jesus Christ is "Lord (that is, Yahweh),"
to the glory of God the Father”.

The connection Paul makes between Isaiah 45:23 and Philippians 2:10-11 is unmistakable.
Paul clearly identifies who Jesus is.
In the Old Testament (Isaiah) it is to Yahweh that every knee will bow and every tongue will confess (that Yahweh is God).
But in the New Testament (Paul) it is to Jesus Christ that every knee should bow and every tongue should confess (that Jesus is Yahweh and hence God) in fulfillment of the Isaiah prophecy!
To me, the connection is as bright as the sun in the sky.
Conclusion
Jesus is the Yahweh of the Old Testament who interacted actively with the patriarchs, Israel and the prophets.

Your conclusion that "Jesus is the Yahweh of the Old Testament"  is modalism.

No, Alex, not at all!

@Nephesh Roi, while you've laid solid groundwork, your conclusion doesn't follow. Jesus affirms his relationship and identity with respect to the Father. Let me suggest considering all the scriptural clues that Jesus provided his disciples, including Hebrews 1, John 1, where Jesus is seated, that Jesus existed before the creation of time, and so on. This will provide a mosaic of understanding. Some of my Christian brothers and sisters from India believe that "Yeshua is the unique avatar of YHWH."

@Dieter – I have double checked the Scripture after reading your comment. (I always recheck my convictions because my intention is not to win an argument but to grasp the truth). I restate my conclusion: Jesus is the Yahweh of the Old Testament who interacted with humanity (face to face with some of them). But no one has seen God the Father at any time as confirmed by Jesus and John! I have updated my post.

Great! Now from John 1:1, we read "In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God." Both with and was. In Hebrews 1:3-4, we read "He is the radiance of the glory of God and the exact imprint of his nature, and he upholds the universe by the word of his power. After making purification for sins, he sat down at the right hand of the Majesty on high . . ." And in Revelation 3:12b, ". . . and my own new name" indicates that Yeshua, Word of Yahweh, will then receive a new name. So, you would need to conclude that Yahweh is not the "Majesty on high," right?

The riddle can be solved when we understand Genesis 18 and 19 chapters. Yahweh with 2 of His angels – all in human forms – appeared to Abraham who immediately recognized his God. Yahweh sent His 2 angels (Gen 19:1) to Sodom and Himself lingered back talking to Abraham (Gen 18:22). Afterwards Yahweh also left to Sodom (verse 33).

Then suddenly we read in Gen 19:24: “And Jehovah rained brimstone and fire on Sodom and Gomorrah, from Jehovah out of the heavens”. This “Jehovah out of the heavens” is the “Majesty on high” you mentioned whom no one has ever seen as per Jesus Himself and John. Yet, Abraham saw (John 8:56) Yahweh who was the “I AM” “before Abraham came to be” (John 8:58)!

Now, Dieter, you who have written with conviction that Jesus is “the EXACT IMPRINT of His nature”, shouldn’t be surprised at this.

Short Answer:
Jesus is not the Creator, but the agent of the Creator. He is the firstborn Son of God, begotten from the Father on Day 1 of the Creation Week before anything else. Only the Father God is the Creator. Jesus was the first of the Creator's works and the beginning of all things; both visible and invisible, animate and inanimate, in heaven or on earth. All things were made through him and for him. Because of Jesus' obedience to God in all things, He has appointed him as heir of all things, as he is preeminent (preexisting) all other things which were created from God alone, yet through His workman Jesus and for his workman Jesus.
Long Answer:
God (the Father) created all things through Jesus Christ (Jn 1:3, Heb 1:2), by ordering him to carry out the work of creating that God ordained him to do (Gen 1:6-26, Prov 8:30, Psa 104:2-30).
Before God created all things through Jesus, God begot (created) Jesus on Day 1 as the Light of the world (Gen 1:3, Jn 8:12, Prov 8:22). After this, God proceeded to carry out the works of physical creation through the Light of the world, that is, through Jesus Christ the Son (Col 1:16); as He is the obedient agent of God who carries out God's perfect orders (Jn 5:19, Lk 22:42).
Jesus preeminent in all things, and the firstborn of creation, because Jesus was the first created creature ever begotten from God, and this occurred on Day 1 in the Creation Week of Genesis (Rev 3:14).
Jesus is the firstborn of all life, and the firstborn from the dead, so that he may be first in everything (Col 1:18).
There is only one God, the Father, from whom are all things, and one Lord, Jesus Christ, through whom are all things (1 Cor 8:6). Jesus becomes preeminent over all things visible and invisible because the Creator has set his agent, Jesus the Son, over the work of the Creator God's hands (redacted portion of Heb 2:7 TR, Psa 8:6 LXX, Hebrews 3:1-4) because all things were made for God and Christ with the sole purpose being to redeem a divine family out of the testing of mortal darkness and into reward of immortal glory, dwelling together within an eternal New Heavens and a New Earth.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
